# How to see images as part of an email in outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I received a safe email in outlook (Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20280) 32-bit) in Windows 10 and the images are not shown as part of the email. I followed the instructions I saw in [this post](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/cannot-see-images-in-outlook-emails-this-post-will-definitely-help/) except the "Clear Temporary File Folder" (which is not described).

Also, the email says on top "You don't often get email from ..."

But although the sender is set to the safe list and I unchecked the "Don't download pictures", the images in the email are not shown. I also restarted outlook, but it did not solve my problem.

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the issue persists in Outlook **safe mode**. If images are shown in safe mode, then the issue might be because of the add-ins. Please also disable firewalls and anti-malware.

We also can review Internet settings:

1. Search Internet Options in the Start menu of your computer.
2. Click the Advanced tab.
3. Go to the Security section and enable the checkbox for Do not save encrypted pages to disk.
4. Click OK.

To **Clear Temporary Files** please refer to https://medicine.arizona.edu/helpdesk-article/clear-temporary-files-windows-7

Did you configure your account on another computer?

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful.  
If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers.